# How to combine two queries in Splunk?

Tags: splunk

I want to make time chart table like this:

[image]

Currently I using two queries

1.Get transaction column :

`sourcetype="mysource" host="myhost" | timechart count span=1h`

2.Get transaction_success column :

`sourcetype="mysource" host="myhost" status="2" | timechart count span=1h`

Then combine them manually with Excel.

How to search that data with only one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

currently i found how to join the queries:

`sourcetype="mysource" host="myhost" | timechart count as transaction count(eval(status="2")) as transaction_success span=1h`

Answer (score 1):

I hope append should work in your case. `Query 1 append Query 2`

Please go thru the following posts in splunk

https://answers.splunk.com/answers/28621/combine-2-splunk-queries.html

https://answers.splunk.com/answers/182453/how-to-combine-my-two-search-queries-using-join-or.html

https://answers.splunk.com/answers/30909/combine-two-queries-into-a-single-value.html

https://answers.splunk.com/answers/123204/how-to-combine-two-queries-into-one-without-using-eventtypes.html